# Elements of a group that fixes a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I am given a problem where $G$ is a group, H is a subgroup of $G$, $A=\{xHx^{-1}:x\in G\}$. In one of the parts, we are asked to find $G_H$ or the subgroup of $G$ consisting of elements that fix $H$. My question is if we are trying to find $\{x\in G:xH=H\}$ or $\{x\in G:xH=Hx\}$ or something else.

Comment: You are trying to find the $x\in G$ such that $xHx^{-1}=H$  (which is the same as your second set, but you want to write it in terms that are similar to the definition of $A$).

Comment: Why is that? Is it given the context of $A$?

Comment: Yes; your $A$ indicates that you are acting on $H$ by conjugation, and when you say “fix $H$”, you mean “fix $H$ under the action being considered”, which is conjugation.

Comment: Is it true in general  that $xHx^{-1}=gHg^{-1}$ if and only if there exists $y\in \{x\in G:xH=Hx\}$ such that xy=g? If, so how do I prove it?

Comment: If $xHx^{-1} = gHg^{-1}$, then $H = x^{-1}gHg^{-1}x = (x^{-1}g)H(x^{-1}g)^{-1}$. So you tell me.

Comment: By the way, this set is itself a subgroup (as you can readily prove), known as the "normalizer" of $H$ in $G$, sometimes denoted $N_G(H)$.